# Issue running SDL Cpp based applicaton

Tags: c++

I Have never used `SDL` and have not coded in C/C++ this last 4 years so I m rusty somehow.

I have found an interesting project on github and I want to run it.

I have a kali linux distribution,

First I installed `DotNet` that I believe is fine since calling `DotNet` from terminal gives response from the console tool. I also installed `CMake`.

Then I successfully installed `SDL2` using the `vcpkg` tool. the compiler is recognizing all the sources dependencies.

But when I run the app I m getting this prompt error

```
[Running] cd "/opt/workspaces/dvr/sdl/Media-Player/" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "/opt/workspaces/dvr/sdl/Media-Player/"main
In file included from main.cpp:1:
Core.h:8:10: fatal error: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory
    8 | #include "SDL2/SDL.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

My sdl2 headers are located on the vcpkg folder in `/opt/workspaces/dvr/vcpkg/packages/sdl2_x64-linux/include/SDL2`

What should I do to fix this

Comment: `-I<path_to_SDL2>` in compile instructions will help you. Or if you are using cmake `target_include_directories()` do the same

Comment: I Will try this right now

Comment: @vsh I succedded using the -I but I dont know how to use the make version, I will google it thanks